# C# CF3.5 trying to get and set useragent on web browser control

Tags: c#, compact-framework

Been searching for a way to get and set the useragent on the web browser control.

This is a mobile app that has to run on older os/hardware so I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and currently CompactFramework 3.5

Here is the code I have right now.

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(int dwOption, String pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int UrlMkGetSessionOption(int dwOption, String pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, ref int pdwBufferLength, int dwReserved);
const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;
```

All of the samples I found say I should have CharSet.Ansi but that's not an option (I assume because of CF 3.5) I tried every option for MarshalAs UnmanagedType but that didn't work it.

Basically what I'm trying to do it set the current user agent for the web browser control and append some additional information on to it.

Comment: When you say "didn't work", what exactly happens? What's the return value of the method? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Anything other then Auto I get not supported.  With Auto I get a crazy negative number for the return value and the buffer is empty.  That is with the Get with the Set I get the crazy negative number and the SET seems to only set 1 character not an entire string.  What I'd like to do it get the current one append something to it and set it.